# How does Dropbox install the App Icon + "Move to Dropbox" global context menu item in Mac OS X Finder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, contextmenu, dropbox, finder

When Dropbox is installed on Mac OS X, it installs a "Move to Dropbox" context menu item when right-clicking on any item in Finder:

[image: Move to Dropbox context menu item]

I would like to install a similar menu item for other my own app. Specifically, I would like an **"Open in AppName"** menu item that allows me to quickly open files in the app without wading through the "Open With..." menu mess.

I have found ways to [add](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/customize-mac-right-click-menu/) Automator [services](http://justaddwater.dk/2009/12/08/how-to-add-open-folder-in-textmate-to-finder-context-menu/) for these actions.

However, these are installed at the bottom of the menu, in "Services". They also **do not have an app icon**, which is key for quickly visually finding the correct menu item in the list.

[image: Open in TextMate menu item service via automator]

I would instead like to exactly replicate the "Move to Dropbox" menu item:

- App Icon is displayed.
- Near top of context menu, not at the very bottom.

What method does Dropbox use? How can I replicate it for my own app?

Does one need to include code for this menu item in the app itself?

Is it possible for the user to add such a menu item for *any* app, similar to automator/services, without touching the app's code?

Comment: Have a look at Services - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267318/creating-an-os-x-service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3946311/64290

Comment: @Volker I mentioned using Services in the question, but they're not nearly as good/usable in the right-click menu as Dropbox's implementation here. Would like to see if the better option is available before using Services.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dropbox is currently using [Finder Sync](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html) extension. You can do all of that using it. Very simple to integrate and implement.